# How to represent NA values as empty pixels (white) for HeatMap in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, heatmap, graphics2d, drawimage

I am using the Java `HeatMap` library (http://www.mbeckler.org/heatMap/) to generate heatMap for my data. 
I am working with a daatset which has NA values. So, basically I want no color (white color) for the pixels which have `NA` value. But, unfortunately this library does not support data with NA value and what I get is a plan block of image with the base color. I tried looking into the source code, so as to make some changes. Within the code, the `drawData()` method is used to color each pixel in the bufferedImage (possibly!). Can someone help me with how I can implement support for NA values and to show them with no color? I have little to no experience with `BufferedImage` and `Graphics2D` class.

Here is the `drawData()` method from the source code of the library:

```
/**
     * Creates a BufferedImage of the actual data plot.
     *
     * After doing some profiling, it was discovered that 90% of the drawing
     * time was spend drawing the actual data (not on the axes or tick marks).
     * Since the Graphics2D has a drawImage method that can do scaling, we are
     * using that instead of scaling it ourselves. We only need to draw the
     * data into the bufferedImage on startup, or if the data or gradient
     * changes. This saves us an enormous amount of time. Thanks to
     * Josh Hayes-Sheen (grey@grevian.org) for the suggestion and initial code
     * to use the BufferedImage technique.
     *
     * Since the scaling of the data plot will be handled by the drawImage in
     * paintComponent, we take the easy way out and draw our bufferedImage with
     * 1 pixel per data point. Too bad there isn't a setPixel method in the
     * Graphics2D class, it seems a bit silly to fill a rectangle just to set a
     * single pixel...
     *
     * This function should be called whenever the data or the gradient changes.
     */
    private void drawData()
    {

      //  System.out.println("Column: " + data.length + " row: " + data[0].length);
        bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(data.length,data[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        bufferedGraphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

        for (int x = 0; x < data.length; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < data[0].length; y++)
            {
                bufferedGraphics.setColor(colors[dataColorIndices[x][y]]);
                bufferedGraphics.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

sample data can be found at: http://www.filedropper.com/data_13

So, this is how it looks at the moment:

From Java:

[image]

From R:

[image]

Please ignore the orientation of the two images

Comment: What is `NA` value? The code above just maps a value (`int index = dataColorIndices[x][y]`)  to a color (`Color c = colors[index]`) and draws it (fills a 1x1 rectangle). So if you map the `NA` value to the color you want (or no color) you'll be good.

Comment: PS: There's also a bug (resource leak) in the code above, it seems to hold on to the `Graphics2D` instance indefinitely. Instead, `bufferedGraphics` should be a local variable, the code should be wrapped in a `try/finally` and `bufferedGraphics` should be `dispose()`'d in the `finally` block.

Comment: What I mean from NA value is there is no signal from that specific pixel. So, this `index` when has NA will show empty pixel. So, I have to put a condition like this an make the `Color c` as white?

Comment: What I meant in the comment above, is, how is NA represented? I'm assuming you have an array of values? How do you represent NA in this array? Is NA a constant like `0` or `-1`, is it `null` or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `BufferedImage` is created as ARGB, you could just not paint anything on those pixels that should be undefined, and they'll stay transparent. Something like:

```
public static int NA = ...;

private void drawData()
{
    bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(data.length,data[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D bufferedGraphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    try {
        for (int x = 0; x < data.length; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < data[0].length; y++)
            {
                int colorIndex = dataColorIndices[x][y];
                if (colorIndex != NA) {
                    bufferedGraphics.setColor(colors[colorIndex]);
                    bufferedGraphics.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
                }
// Alternate flow, if you really want the pixels to be white
//                else {
//                    bufferedGraphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
//                    bufferedGraphics.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
//                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        bufferedGraphics.dispose();
    }
}
```

I also dispose the `Graphics2D` instance, to avoid resource leaks.

Comment: Wonderful, it works :) Although it didnot somehow work for the NA, I converted the NA values to zero and I get the desired results. Another quick question, is the code rounding off the values somehow? Because, when I generate the image in R, I get the exact heatmap I am looking for, but in Java, I am getting a single colored block.

Comment: @novicegeek There's no rounding in the code above. But I don't know the library you are using (or R for that matter), so there could be rounding/scaling of your input values somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Yes, possibly I will look for that. I just updated the images in my question above. These are images for the same data matrix, generated using R and Java.